# Django rest framework: omit dict where field is empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a rest API for a media library.

Here are some of my python code, I have simplify them a bit, so only the necessary code is included, to have a better overview about the current problem.

**models.py:**

```py
class MediaSeries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)


class MediaSeriesEntries(models.Model):
    serie = models.ForeignKey(MediaSeries, related_name='series',
                              db_column='seriesID', null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    file = models.ForeignKey(MediaFiles, related_name='serie_set',
                             db_column='fileID', null=True,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class MediaFiles(models.Model):
    youtube = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    screeningPause = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    duration = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    creatingDate = models.DateTimeField(default=now)


class Library(models.Model):
    media = models.ForeignKey(MediaFiles, related_name='library_set',
                              db_column='fileID', null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py:**

```py
class LibraryMediaFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Library
        fields = ['media__name', 'media__duration',
                  'media__youtube', 'media__creatingDate']


class LibraryMediaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows the library to be viewed.

    Example ordering:
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/library-media/?ordering=media__creatingDate
    """
    queryset = Library.objects.all() \
        .exclude(media__youtube="").exclude(media__screeningPause=True)
    serializer_class = LibraryMediaSerializer
    pagination_class = LibraryResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    filterset_class = LibraryMediaFilter
    ordering_fields = ['media__serie_set__serie__name', 'media__name',
                       'media__creatingDate', 'visits', 'likes']
```

**serializers.py:**

```py
class LibraryMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='media.name', read_only=True)
    duration = serializers.IntegerField(source='media.duration',
                                        read_only=True)
    youtube = serializers.CharField(source='media.youtube', read_only=True)
    creatingDate = serializers.DateTimeField(source='media.creatingDate',
                                             read_only=True)
    serie_set = SeriesEntriesSerializer(source='media.serie_set',
                                        read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Library
        fields = ('visits', 'likes', 'name', 'duration', 'youtube',
                  'creatingDate', 'serie_set')
```

When I call now the api with `http://example.org/api/library-media/` I get this result:

```
{
    "visits": 0,
    "likes": 0,
    "name": "example movie",
    "duration": 9505000,
    "youtube": "https://youtu.be/34345",
    "creatingDate": "2013-01-01T01:00:00+01:00",
    "serie_set": []
},
{
    "visits": 0,
    "likes": 0,
    "name": "example serie",
    "duration": 3436000,
    "youtube": "https://youtu.be/z0c4rLCcyVE",
    "creatingDate": "2013-01-01T01:00:00+01:00",
    "serie_set": [
        {
            "name": "Das große Ganze",
            "description": ""
        }
    ]
},
```

Now I would like to filter against empty and not empty `serie_set`, with something like:

`http://example.org/api/library-media/media__serie_set__isempty=true`

or:

`http://example.org/api/library-media/media__serie_set__isempty=false`

Comment: why don't you filter your queryset?

Comment: But how can I filter when my request should return something "not empty"? Or do I misunderstand this?

Comment: `.exclude(youtube="")`

Comment: Thank you!, I didn't know that this exists.

Comment: This is still useful, but I also neede a dynamic solution, where I can filter empty strings, or lists in specific fields. For example: `*?youtube_isempty=false`. Are you so kind to give me a keyword for that to?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *?

Comment: Sorry, that is just a placeholder: `http://example.org/api/media?youtube_isempty=false`

Comment: I don't understand, what's the field name and what should not be empty?

Comment: are you trying to match strings that do not contain the characters "youtube"?

Comment: I used youtube, because I had it in top post json result. For this example I would like to filter everything what has an empty youtube field, or it has a string in it. Like: `youtube_isempty=false` or `youtube_isempty=true`. It must be a bit generic, because I would like to use it on fields, which contains lists, the list can be empty to: `{list: []}`

Comment: It depends on your model field. If your model field is a `CharField` then empty means "empty string" and you can filter not empty using `exclude(field="")` and empty using `filter(field="")`. But if it's a list (ArrayField?) then you need to test for empty list, if it's an IntegerField you need to test for `NULL` (`field__isnull=True`) etc...

Comment: Yes this I understand. The list comes from a foreign key with multiple matches. As I understand `exclude` and `filter` are static? I can not influence this by request - right? But now that you've mentioned the IntegerField: maybe I could do something like `.annotate(item_count=Count('list'))` with the list, and then make a request with: `item_count__isnull=True`. Is this working?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by static and influence by request. You should show concrete code examples of what you’re trying to do. And yes, you can annotate with Count.

Comment: I have update the top post, hopefully is now more clear.

Comment: Can't you just filter with `media__serie_set__isnull=True`?

Comment: No is not working, but I have add to my queryset now: `.annotate(serie_count=Count('media__serie_set'))` and in my filter class I added: `serie_count = filters.NumberFilter(field_name='serie_count')` and now I can filter with: `serie_count=0` or `serie_count=1`. It works and I guess is good enough. Thank you for giving helpful thoughts!